# Calculating NPS using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am very, very new to Python and am playing around with how I would calculate an NPS score.

The calculation is:

> (count of scores 9-10/total count of scores 0-10) - (count of scores
>   0-6/total count of scores 0-10) for each council.

Data Frame I am using:

[image]

The NPS would need to be calculated for each council separately.
This is my first post on here, hopefully it makes sense. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Cheers, 
Ben.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: @ Ben, what is desired output, are you looking something where NPS is greater than equals to 9 ? However if you have tried something then put that as well  as it will help what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @pygo Do you mean what is the expected answer? Sorry, I am just getting to know the etiquette on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BenSwann, yes indeed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is in `data.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

high_nps = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
low_nps = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

high_nps.update(dict(df[df['NPS'] >= 9].groupby('CouncilName').count().reset_index()[['CouncilName', 'NPS']].values))
low_nps.update(dict(df[df['NPS'] <= 6].groupby('CouncilName').count().reset_index()[['CouncilName', 'NPS']].values))
total_nps = dict(df.groupby('CouncilName').count().reset_index()[['CouncilName', 'NPS']].values)

nps_score = {council: (high_nps[council] - low_nps[council]) / float(total_nps[council])  for council in total_nps}

print(nps_score)
```

Prints:

```
{'Council A': 0.0, 'Council B': -1.0, 'Council C': -1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def npsForField(df,column,fid):
    nps={}

    # first make sure our column has numeric values:
    subject = pd.DataFrame(columns=[column],data=pd.to_numeric(df[df['field_id']==fid][column]))

    # calculate all NPS components:
    nps['total']      = subject[column].count()
    nps['detractors'] = subject[subject[column]<7][column].count()
    nps['passives']   = subject[(subject[column]>6) & (subject[column]<9)][column].count()
    nps['promoters']  = subject[subject>8][column].count()

    nps['nps']        = (nps['promoters'] - nps['detractors']) / nps['total']

    return nps
```

Then suppose you want to calculate the NPS for a column of `df` called `answer`, but only where `df[df['field_id']==fid]`. Call it like this:

```
npsForField(df, column='answer', fid='abc123')
```

Sample result:

```
{'total': 979,
 'detractors': 313,
 'passives': 291,
 'promoters': 375,
 'nps': 0.06332992849846783}
```